# Add Stylesheet reference to XML Document in Linq?

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I create an XML Doc and wanted have a reference to the XSLT file.

```
//<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="OBReport.xslt"?>
```

to this XML generation:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("ReportedOn",
                    from dl in EL.DocumentLog.ToList()
                    join o in EL.Organization
                    on dl.OrganizationID equals o.OrganizationId
                    where dl.ActionDate >= stDate &
                    dl.ActionDate <= enDate 
                    orderby dl.DefendantName, dl.DocumentName
                    select new XElement("persons",
                              new XAttribute("documentName", dl.DocumentName),
                              new XElement("defendantName", dl.DefendantName),
                              new XElement("actionDate", dl.ActionDate.ToString()),
                              new XElement("startDate", dl.StartDate.ToString()),
                           new XElement("endDate", dl.EndDate.ToString()),
                           new XElement("organizationName" , o.OrganizationName) ));
```

Comment: @Henk Holterman: It makes no difference if the OP wants to add a PI for XSLT stylesheet or CSS stylesheet. Also, to reference a XSLT stylesheet into an XML document is not part of XSLT specifications. And last, the OP wants to do this with LINQ, no with XSLT itself. So, please rollback your title and tag edition.

Comment: @Alejandro: No, the Processing Instruction is part of the answer, not of the question. And I found PI to cryptic.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I think that this `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="OBReport.xslt"?>` (textual from question) **is a PI...**. But that has nothing to do with my preceding arguments

Comment: @Alejandro: Questions titles are also a form of SEO. someone who knows this is a ProcessingInstruction won't be searching for this question.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Fair enough! That's why I refrase as "Stylesheet reference".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add an [XProcessingInstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xprocessinginstruction?view=netframework-4.7.1) element.

And not to your XElement (which can be used as a document but with limitations) but to an enveloping [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xdocument-class-overview). So, after your code:

```
 XElement body = ...; // root XElement from your Linq statement 
 XDocument doc = new XDocument(
      new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' ref='hello.xsl'"), 
      body);
```