# C# Webservice response xml displaying as pdf

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am new to C# web development. I am developing a software that receives response from webservice in XML format. (includes barcodes generated by webservice). 
There is an option given by webservice provider, that i have to add a line 
(Example`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`) 
as a second line in the xml and display in web browser by using style sheets provided by webservice provider. If i have to choose this option, how can i add that line as second line in the received xml file also how can i map the style sheets provided by the webserive in the project for this xml.
If i dont take that option, Is it possible to display the data in xml as a pdf(includes barcodes generated by webservice), if i dont choose the option .

Comment: Looks like they want you to do an [XsltCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) but without a scaled down example, an [MCVE] and attempt from you this question is too broad to be answered. It could help if you link us to the service provider documentation that you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to:

1. **Add a stylesheet** specification to an existing XML
2. Convert an **XML to PDF**

---

**1. ADDING A STYLESHEET**

> There is an option given by webservice provider, that i have to add a line [...] as a second line in the xml and display in web browser by using style sheets

This is done using e.g. Linq, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680559/add-stylesheet-reference-to-xml-document-in-linq).
First of all, I think the example you used, i.e.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

may be inaccurate, as it is the first line of a XSL file (a stylesheet); those kind of files are used to transform an XML into another file (a different XML or an HTML, like in your case). However, you say

> using style sheets provided by webservice provider

so my guess is that you already have those stylesheets and you can you use them, rather than creating them yourself.
If so, the line you want to add is like

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="helloWorld.xsl"?>
```

Let's suppose you already have your XML stored into an `XDocument` variable named "Document" with its root element being "Root"

```
var FilePath = "Example.xml";
var Document = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
var Root = XDocument.Descendants("Root").Single();
```

Then you can add your stylesheet this way, getting a new XML:

```
var NewDocument = new XDocument(
     new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl'ref='helloWorld.xsl'"),
     Root);
```

---

**2. XML to PDF**

There are several ways to do this.
 
You might parse your XML, retrieve the elements you want to show on your PDF, use a library like iTextSharp to create a specific layout and place their contents on the file.
 
Or, since you already have an XML and you can transform it to an HTML using an XSL, you can use wkHtmlToPdf.
Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you... This is what i am looking for... thank you for guiding me...

Comment: No problem, ask if you need something else.