# How do I generate this XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have an example XML file that I need to generate on the fly in a console application.

This is an example of the first part of the required XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ABC123.xsl" ?>
<CPPData xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CPPData_V1.14.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Envelope>
        <EnvelopeNode NumOrdre="1">
        </EnvelopeNode>
    </Envelope>
</CPPData>
```

I have a method creates and returns an XElement which contains all the data required by the body of the XML (e.g. everything inside the CPPData element).

However I can't figure out how to add the following:

1. `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ABC123.xsl" ?>` to the XDocument
2. `<CPPData xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CPPData_V1.14.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` to the XElement

Comment: For the `<?xml-stylesheet`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680559/add-stylesheet-reference-to-xml-document-in-linq

Comment: For the second, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324960/creating-xdocument-with-xsischemalocation-namespace (but obviously replace schemaLocation with noNamespaceSchemaLocation)

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var xml = new XDocument();
var xp = new XProcessingInstruction(target: "xml-stylesheet", data: @"type=""text/xsl"" href=""ABC123.xsl""");
xml.Add(xp);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
xml.Add(new XElement("root",
          new XAttribute(ns + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "CPPData_V1.14.xsd"),
          new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
));
```